# Resolve error 'there is no argument given that corresponds to required formal parameter'?

Tags: c#, oop

I have following code where I'm getting error while compiling in C# visual Studio 2015.

```
class Oval:Shape
{
    private double major_axis, minor_axis;
    public Oval(double Major_Axis, double Minor_Axis)
    {
      major_axis = Major_Axis;
      minor_axis = Minor_Axis;
    } //Constructor
}
class Circle:Oval
{
    private double radius;
    public Circle(double Circle_Radius) // Getting Error on this line
    {
      radius = Circle_Radius;  
    } //constructor
}
```

Comment: As an aside, now would be a good time to start learning about .NET naming conventions.

Comment: But it's easier for everyone to read if you *do* follow the naming conventions. Why do you think conventions are useful for your real code but not in sample code?

Comment: In the latest update I have followed all of the conventions. Thanks .

Comment: **SAME ERROR WITH NO CODING MISTAKES** - CLOSE AND OPEN THE SOLUTION

Answer (score 45, accepted):

**Fixing your bug:**

The error occurs due to the lack of a parameterless constructor (or your lack of using the `base()` method in your constructor (just like `user3185569` had said)

**Fixing your code:**

It clearly seems you are lacking some basics in .NET so I've decided to give a re-writing to your code with the following things in mind:

a. **Conventions**

There are some rules about common conventions that should apply to your code.

Members usually begin with either `m` or `_` and then the `memberName` (camel casing).

Properties are usually written regularly as `PropertyName` and same applies to methods.

Parameters and variables are simply camel cased like `parameterName`

b. **Access Modifiers**

I don't know the use of your Oval and circle but I assume you'd want to access them outside of `Oval` and `Circle`.

I think it would be the best to reference you to here to read some more about the topic: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx

I've re-written your code to include all those tips (and also fix your issue)

```
public class Oval:Shape
{       
    //Constructor
    public Oval(double majorAxis, double minorAxis)
    {
        MajorAxis=majorAxis;
        MinorAxis=minorAxis;
    } 
    
    protected double MajorAxis{ get; set; }     
    protected double MinorAxis{ get; set; }     
}    

public class Circle:Oval
{       
    //Constructor
    public Circle(double radius): base(radius,radius)
    {
        radius = Circle_Radius;  
    }
    
    public double Radius
    {
        get
        {
            return MajorAxis;
        }
        set
        {
            MajorAxis = value;
            MinorAxis = value;
        }       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 23):

Since `Circle` inherits from `Oval`, when you create a `Circle` the default constructor for `Oval` is called in your case. Since that constructor accepts 2 parameters, you need to explicitly call the constructor and provide them:

```
class Circle : Oval
{
    private double radius;
    public Circle(double Circle_Radius) : base(0, 0) // change to whatever values
    {
      radius = Circle_Radius;  
    }
}
```

So A `Circle` is an `Oval`, so it has `major_axis` and `minor_axis` values. You just didn't provide them as they are required values to create an `Oval`.

Of course you can add a default public constructor for `Oval` with no parameters, but that makes you create a Oval with no `major_axis` and `minor_axis` and both seems required by the only constructor in the current status of your code. So, you need to rethink how to design your classes.

Comment: If in case, you don't want to provide the values to the constructor of Class `Oval` , then you can define a `parameterless constructor` in the Oval Class.                                                                                        `public Oval()
    {
      major_axis = 0;
      minor_axis = 0;
    }`

Comment: @RichaGarg I hesitated in stating that myself because this way you are able to create an `Oval` with no major and minor axis. Which doesn't seem the case the OP wanted. This raised questions about designing for inheritance, but things are just not that clear for me.

Comment: yes you are right! Everything depends on design. However, by this approach, we can define some default values to major and minor axis.

Answer (score 3):

You need to update your base class constructor to the following:

````
class Oval:Shape
{
    private double major_axis, minor_axis;
    public Oval(double Major_Axis, double Minor_Axis)
    {
      major_axis = Major_Axis;
      minor_axis = Minor_Axis;
    } //Constructor
}
class Circle:Oval
{
    private double radius;
    public Circle(double Circle_Radius):base(12.2,12.2) // pass value to base class constructor
    {
      radius = Circle_Radius;  
    } //constructor
}~```
````

Answer (score 1):

Uou can also add an empty constructor in Base class.

```
public Shape() {}
```

or

```
public Oval() {}
```

This will not enforce you using 2 arguments constructor.

Answer (score -1):

```
class Oval : Shape   
{        
    #region Constants
    private const double dblPIE = 3.14d;
    #endregion

    #region Member_Variables
    private double m_dblMajorRad = 0.0d;
    private double m_dblMinorRad = 0.0d;
    #endregion


    #region Constructors
    /// <summary>
    /// default constructor
    /// </summary>
    public Oval()
    {

    }
    /// <summary>
    /// initializes Major Radius and Minor Radius of oval
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="dblOvalMajorRad"></param>
    /// <param name="dblOvalMinorRad"></param>
    public Oval(double dblOvalMajorRad, double dblOvalMinorRad)
    {
        m_dblMajorRad = dblOvalMajorRad;
        m_dblMinorRad = dblOvalMinorRad;
    }
    #endregion
}

class Circle : Oval
{
    #region Constants
    private const double dblPIE = 3.14d;
    #endregion

    #region Member_Variables
    private double m_dblRadius = 0.0d;
    #endregion

    #region Constructors
    /// <summary>
    /// initializes radius
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="dblRadius"></param>
    public Circle(double dblRadius)
    {
        m_dblRadius = dblRadius;
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Posting code only as an answer is not a good practice on StackOverflow. My answer directs you toward the real problem, so I find no reason for you to revert it back as not accepted. Also, the solution your provided is stated in the comments of my answer and also it is stated why it is not a good option.

Comment: @Dhiraj-sardal You need to state in words describing the code you have modified.