# How do you inject a repo into a service in ASP.Net Core MVC

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a really odd problem.
I have defined a Repository for a DbSet Called PageHits.

This is the interface:

```
public interface IPageHitRepo
{
    IQueryable<PageHit> PageHits { get; }
    void AddPageHit(PageHit pageHit);
    void SaveChanges();
}
```

This is the implementation:

```
public class PageHitRepo : IPageHitRepo
{
    private CtasContext _context;
    
    public PageHitRepo(CtasContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public IQueryable<PageHit> PageHits => _context.PageHits;

    public void AddPageHit(PageHit pageHit)
    {
        _context.Add(pageHit);
    }

    public void SaveChanges()
    {
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

I configure in startup.ConfigureServices like this:

```
services.AddScoped<IPageHitRepo, PageHitRepo>();
```

This is all just normal stuff.  I use this to inject into controllers all the time using constructor injection.
But right now I want to inject this repo service into another service called PageHitService.

It has a lot going on but the injection part should be simple.
I have a IPageHitService interface defined like this:

```
public interface IPageHitService
{
    // Default implimentation overridden in PageHitService.
    Task Invoke(IServiceProvider sp) => Task.FromResult(true); 
    Task EmailSiteHitNotification(PageHit pageHit, IServiceProvider sp);
    Task LogPageHitToDB(PageHit pageHit, IServiceProvider sp);
}
```

Then the top of the PageHitService looks like this:

```
public class PageHitService : IPageHitService
{
    private IPageHitRepo _pageHitRepo;
    public PageHitService(IPageHitRepo pageHitRepo)
    {
        _pageHitRepo = pageHitRepo;
    }
    
    public async Task Invoke(IServiceProvider sp)
    {
        HttpContext httpContext =
            sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>().HttpContext;
        IWebHostEnvironment env = sp.GetRequiredService<IWebHostEnvironment>();
        IConfiguration config = sp.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();
        // _context = sp.GetRequiredService<CtasContext>();

        bool visitSet =
            !string.IsNullOrEmpty(httpContext.Session.GetString("VisitSet"));
```

and here is the registration in StartUp.ConfigureServices:

```
services.AddScoped<IPageHitService, PageHitService>();
```

But when I try to compile I get this error:

There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'pageHitRepo' of 'PageHitService.PageHitService(IPageHitRepo)'

Why do we not get this error in constructors?
The way I understand DI in .Net Core is it looks at the constructor in the controller and if it sees a dependency it resolves it by the registration in startup and then if it sees a dependency in the service it is resolving it resolves that service's dependency and so on.

Why is it giving me this error.
I understand if I make a default paramterless constructor the error goes away but then ASP.Net Core DI does not know which constructor to use and both constructors get hit and my page ends up with a 500 error and cannot be shown.

### What am I missing here?

**Update 1:**

Don't know if this can help.
But in answer to Steve's comment below I do have a BaseController class and a Base PageModel.

```
public class BaseController : Controller
    {
        public BaseController(IServiceProvider sp)
        {
            IPageHitService pageHitService = sp.GetRequiredService<IPageHitService>();
            // pageHitService.Invoke(sp).Await();
            pageHitService.Invoke(sp).Wait();
        }

        #region Callbacks if you use AsyncMethod.Await() extension method.
        private void Completed()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Completed pageHitService.Invoke from BaseController");
        }

        private void HandleError(Exception ex)
        {
            // TODO: Log Error to DB;
        }
        #endregion

    }

public class BasePageModel : PageModel
{
     public BasePageModel(IServiceProvider sp)
    {
        IPageHitService pageHitService = sp.GetRequiredService<IPageHitService>();
        // pageHitService.Invoke(sp).Await();
        pageHitService.Invoke(sp).Wait();
    }

    #region Callbacks if you use AsyncMethod.Await() extension method.
    private void Completed()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Completed pageHitService.Invoke from BaseController");
    }

    private void HandleError(Exception ex)
    {
        // TODO: Log Error to DB;
    }
    #endregion
}
```

But I can't see this affecting the constructor and causing an error there.

**Update 2**
I found the offending code in the PageHitService:

```
PageHitService pageHitService = new PageHitService();
```

Invoke was static because I was fooling around with going the factory route.
And I could not call the non-static methods so I had to instantiate an instance to call the 2 methods in the API.
Nothing is static now so I am going to comment out that line and just try to call the methods straight up.

Here is the full class:

```
public class PageHitService : IPageHitService
{
    private IPageHitRepo _pageHitRepo;
    
    public PageHitService(IPageHitRepo pageHitRepo)
    {
        _pageHitRepo = pageHitRepo;
    }
    
    public async Task Invoke(IServiceProvider sp)
    {
        HttpContext httpContext =
            sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>().HttpContext;
        IWebHostEnvironment env = sp.GetRequiredService<IWebHostEnvironment>();
        IConfiguration config = sp.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();
        // _context = sp.GetRequiredService<CtasContext>();

        bool visitSet =
            !string.IsNullOrEmpty(httpContext.Session.GetString("VisitSet"));

        PageHit PageHit = new PageHit
        {
            SessionID = httpContext.Session.Id,
            UserIP = httpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString(),
            EnvironmentName = env.EnvironmentName,
            Url = httpContext.Request.PathBase + httpContext.Request.Path,
            ReferrerUrl = httpContext.Request.Headers["Referer"].ToString(),
            DateTime = DateTime.Now
        };

        PageHitService pageHitService = new PageHitService();
        bool logPageHitsOn = bool.Parse(config["LogPageHitsOn"]);
        bool emailSiteHitNotificationsOn = bool.Parse(config["EmailSiteHitNotificationsOn"]);
        if (!visitSet)
        {
            // create session
            httpContext.Session.SetString("VisitSet", "true");

            // Emails (1st visit of session)
            if (emailSiteHitNotificationsOn)
            {
                await pageHitService.EmailSiteHitNotification(PageHit, sp);
            }
        }

        // Logs all PageHits to DB.
        if (logPageHitsOn)
        {
            await pageHitService.LogPageHitToDB(PageHit, sp);
        }
    }

    public async Task EmailSiteHitNotification(PageHit pageHit,
        IServiceProvider sp)
    {
        IEmailService emailService = sp.GetRequiredService<IEmailService>();

        StringBuilder body = new StringBuilder();
        body.AppendFormat($"<b>SessionID:</b> {pageHit.SessionID}");
        body.Append("<br /><br />");
        body.AppendFormat($"<b>User Ip:</b> {pageHit.UserIP}");
        body.Append("<br /><br />");
        body.AppendFormat($"<b>Environment:</b> {pageHit.EnvironmentName}");
        body.Append("<br /><br />");
        body.AppendFormat($"<b>Url (Page Hit):</b> {pageHit.Url}");
        body.Append("<br /><br />");
        body.AppendFormat($"<b>ReferrerUrl:</b> {pageHit.ReferrerUrl}");
        body.Append("<br /><br />");
        body.AppendFormat($"<b>DateTime:</b> {pageHit.DateTime}");
        body.Append("<br /><br />");

        string subject = "CTAS Hit Notification";

        await emailService.SendEmail(body.ToString(), subject);
    }

    public async Task LogPageHitToDB(PageHit pageHit,
        IServiceProvider sp)
    {
        CtasContext context = sp.GetRequiredService<CtasContext>();
        await context.PageHits.AddAsync(pageHit);
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: There is something going on in your code, which you don't show in the question. As it currently stands your problem is not reproducible. Your question, therefore, needs details or clarity. Did you perhaps not make an identical copy of your code? Might it be that there is also a (base) class called `IPageHitService`? Take a look for instance at this SO [q/a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38758760/resolve-error-there-is-no-argument-given-that-corresponds-to-required-formal-pa).

Comment: @Steven - will thanks for looking.  No base class for this service.  I do have a base controller and a base PageModel that call the service. 
I'll post the those in the question.

Comment: If I add a private constructor: the compile error goes away.
Is this because I have a default implementation on one of the Interface Members of the IPageHitService?

Comment: @Steven - thanks for the comment though it jogged my eyes to see it. I was up until 2:00 am trying to figure out how to call my async methods from a constructor.  That's why I was trying to create a static factory method to call the the async methods.  The email async works but hte DbContext asyncs were not working.  And I was getting object disposed for the DbContext.  I read you can get rid of that message by constructor injection over sp.GetRequiredService.  So I made a repo and am working on injecting that.  Maybe async will work.  LogPageHitToDb.Wait() works but I don't want that.

Comment: You should almost never call `IServiceProvider.GetService`. this will easily be riddled with troubles. You should simply ctor-inject those dependencies.

Comment: Nah,  that's what it's there for.  DI is quite powerful now.  If you have a base page that needs 20 dependancies I'm not going to sit there and pass all 20 to the constructor from a hundred pages.  This is what it is for.

Comment: The problems I'm having have absolutely nothing to do with GetRequiredService.  It's quite reliable.

Comment: I disagree with all of that. GetService might accidentally pull things in from the root container, which might explain why you get an ObjectDisposedEx. And base classes with 20 dependencies might be an indication there is a problem with that class. Using IServiceProvider should be limited to the Composition Root.

Comment: @Steven - But I do appreciate your help.  Repo is working through Dependancy injection.  Whoot.  BTW - Constructor injection is my preferred approach.  Just trying out some other things here while reading some 3.1 stuff

Comment: Great that it's working. Can I suggest a good book about Dependency Injector for you to broaden your knowledge? Dependency Injection Principles, Practices, and Patterns (coauthored by me).

Comment: If you want a good deep dive book on everything check this guy out:
https://www.apress.com/gp/book/9781484203972