# Why am I getting this error in my C# script? There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'Type'

Tags: c#, parameters, arguments

Here is what I am trying to do but unfortunately I am getting the above error:

```
void Function1() { 
    if() { 
        Function2(); 
    } 

    else {…} 
    } 

public static void Function2 (Type type) {
…
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Resolve error 'there is no argument given that corresponds to required formal parameter'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38758760/resolve-error-there-is-no-argument-given-that-corresponds-to-required-formal-pa)

Comment: Should be something like `public static void Function2(Type myType)`, a parameter has a type and a name.

Comment: Thank you that is what I'm trying but its still showing error

Comment: Woops, almost forgot ! Don't forget then to pass the actual parameter in `Function1` 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss the param name in your `Function2`.

```
public static void Function2 (Type)
```

It should be:

```
public static void Function2 (Type type)
```

Based on your `Function1` implementation, you didn't pass with the parameter to `Function2`. That will be another issue.

> No overload for method 'Function2' takes 0 arguments

If the `Function2` can be accepted with no argument, you can do it with

1. Method overloading (Declare another Function2 with no parameter)

```
public static void Function2 () { }
```

2. Change current `Function2` with optional parameter

```
public static void Function2 (Type type = null) { }
```

**UPDATED**:

As the Post owner mentioned `Function2` requires 1 parameter, thus in your `Function1()`, you need to pass the value to call `Function2`.

```
void Function1() 
{ 
    if(/* when condition is true */)
    { 
        Function2(/* pass your value */); 
    } 
    else {…} 
}
```

Comment: Sorry the param name was there actually, its Type type I just didn't add it, I will fix it. I'm still getting the error

Comment: Hi @jsmith, can you mention what is the problem you faced? Is it due to a missing parameter when calling `Function2` in your `Function1()` ?

Comment: Function 2 has parameters set up correctly, however, only when I add the line Function2(); to Function 1 I get the error

Comment: That's due to the missing parameter when you call `Function2()` as I mentioned in the answer. You need to pass the value as like `Function2(your_value)` in your `Function1()`. I have updated my answer. You may review it. Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean the value or the name of the parameter? I placed the parameters into Funtion2(); as well but not it says syntax error ',' required (which I am using already)

Comment: Hi @jsmith, see my answer. For syntax error ',', this is not relevant with this question. There will somewhere you mistype ',' and you need to review the source code since I don't have the complete source code. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you, the value of Type needs to come from another script and function. I added in Type type to both instances of Function2(); but it says syntax error now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231565/discussion-between-jsmith-and-yong-shun).