# I'm having some issues referencing a class to another class and the error I'm getting is I don't have an argument for a formal perimeter

Tags: c#

I have a Player class and I am trying to reference that class to my Main class. but I put some code in there that's giving me an error when I try and reference it to my main class. there is no given argument that corresponds to the required formal perimeter, 'statName' of 'Player.PLayer(string, int)' can someone help me? I'm pretty sure it has to do with mushing all the code together but I just don't know and am wanting a little help. here are my classes.

here is my program class

```
class Program
{
    PLayer Playerstat = new PLayer(); // I'm trying to reference the class Player here but it's not letting me.
    
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("please pick a mode");
        PLayGame();
        PickMode();
       


        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static void PLayGame()
    {
        List<string> Options = new List<string> { "Easy mode: ", "med mode: ", "Hard mode", "super hard mode: " };
        

        foreach(string ModePick in Options)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(570);
            Console.WriteLine(ModePick);
        }
    }

    private static void PickMode()
    {
        string pick = Console.ReadLine();
        if (pick == "easy")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("you have picked easy.");
        }
            
    }

    
}
```

and here is my Player class

```
public class PLayer
{
    public string Name;
    private int _statValue;
    private string _statName;
    public bool Dead;

    public PLayer(string statName, int statValue)
    {
        _statName = statName;
        _statValue = statValue;
    }

    public override string ToString() => _statName + ": " + _statValue;

    List<PLayer> stats = new List<PLayer>
    { new("Health", 100),
      new("Accuracy", 89),
      new("Blade Amount", 2),
      new("Blade Damage", 20),
      new("Blade Lanth", 40),
      new("Blade durablity", 50),
      new("Col", 0)
    };

    //all the NPCs you know. 
    List<string> Npc = new List<string> { "levi: ", "Armin: ", "Mikasa: ", "Hange: ", "Erwin: " };
    //skills for killing titans
    List<string> Skills = new List<string>();

    public void PrintStats()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("your stats are: ");
        foreach (var stat in stats)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(575);
            Console.WriteLine(stat.ToString());
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: The constructor for `PLayer` takes two arguments. You didn't pass any. Try replacing your first line with `PLayer Playerstat = new PLayer("Health", 100);`

Comment: You're not passing any parameters to the constructor of your Player class that you're trying to invoke. The only constructor for that class takes a statName and statValue parameters. You either need to provide those when you invoke the constructor (ex, `new Player("Mason", 32)` or add another constructor to the player class that doesn't take any parameters.

Comment: how might I pass some? and I want to reference it because I want to call the method printStats.

Comment: I showed how to pass the parameters in my prior comment. You would probably benefit from reading [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constructors).

Comment: Your `PLayer` class is creating a list inside of it which contains more `PLayer`s when it seems the intent is to have a list of skills in each player. As it stands now, your PrintStats will print the same thing for every instance of `PLayer` that you make.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Resolve error 'there is no argument given that corresponds to required formal parameter'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38758760/resolve-error-there-is-no-argument-given-that-corresponds-to-required-formal-pa)

Comment: Perhaps run a find "PL", replace "Pl" to improve readability; experienced C# devs will automatically read it as two words: P Layer

Comment: When declaring variables inside methods, name them with an initial lower case letter: `camelCase`. The `PascalCase` you're using is conventionally used for public members of a class; a c# dev reading `foreach(string ModePick in Options)` would expect `Options` to be a public class level property, not a local variable. They would expect `ModePick` to be `modePick` or, better, `option`. Strive for consistency;  `List<PLayer> stats` shoukd be called `List<Player> _stats` like your other private class level variables, and it should be at the top of the class.

Comment: `Npc` and `Skills` should be `_npc` and `_skills` and `_npc` should have a plural name because it's a collection

Answer (score 1):

1. Names like "PLayer" (both "P" and "L" capitalized) are just asking for trouble.

   BEST PRACTICE: Use [PascalCase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/coding-conventions#pascal-case), e.g. `class Player`
2. Use namespaces.  MSVS will do this for you by default (if you're using the Visual Studio IDE); you didn't show us whether you're using them yourself.

   Using namespaces makes it easy to qualify your class names when referring to objects that are in different modules.
3. MAIN PROBLEM:

   If you want `Player Playerstat = new Player()` ... then you need to declare a [no-args ("parameterless") constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-constructors) for "Player"!

Comment: I always thought the two options in programming were either "Title Case" (as in `FileSystemWatcher` class) or "Camel case" (as in `myFileSystemWatcherVariable`). Reading about it now I see it is [ambiguous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) with its first letter being either upper or lower.  Confusing. :/  +1 nonetheless

Comment: @MickyD As with most programming languages,i n C# there is a lot of freedom in choice of naming conventions. Microsoft does, however, have defined conventions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/coding-conventions. What you refer to as "Title Case" Microsoft calls Pascal case, and Camel case is similar, but the first letter is not upper-case. You don't have to follow any of these conventions though if you choose not to.

Comment: *You don't have to follow any of these conventions though* you do if you don't want a lecture (from me) on SO though! 

Comment: (but seriously, we have naming conventions for valid reasons; do please encourage people to follow them rather than declaring  them optional)

Comment: The reasons are valid yes. I understand why people encourage the use of code conventions; however, it doesn't make the code invalid if their syntax is wrong. If someone is trying to learn to code, conventions are important but actually understanding what is going on is more important. That being said, I agree -- totally expect to be corrected on syntax if you post code on SO! (Especially when the intent is to share code and have succinct Q & A )

Answer (score 1):

You have several issues with your code, a HUGE one being a **Stack Overflow Error**.

The way your `PLayer` class is designed causes an infinite loop if you were to have created it properly in the first place.

First, to fix the error you are seeing, you'll want to pass in parameters into the **Constructor** of your `PLayer` class.

In your `PLayer` class you have a constructor:

```
public PLayer(string statName, int statValue)
    {
        _statName = statName;
        _statValue = statValue;
    }
```

Which requires you to supply a `string` `statName` and an `int` `statValue` whenever you instantiate your `PLayer`.

So in your `Program` the line you have written as:

`PLayer Playerstat = new PLayer(); // I'm trying to reference the class Player here but it's not letting me.`

Needs to be changed to something like:

`PLayer Playerstat = new PLayer("ExampleString", 1); // I'm trying to reference the class Player here but it's not letting me.`

However, that's not the main issue here. If you end up fixing that, you'll go to run your program and get hit with a Stack Overflow error. The reason being, your `PLayer` class, upon instantiation, tries to create a `List<PLayer>` within itself with your code:

```
List<PLayer> stats = new List<PLayer>
    { new("Health", 100),
      new("Accuracy", 89),
      new("Blade Amount", 2),
      new("Blade Damage", 20),
      new("Blade Lanth", 40),
      new("Blade durablity", 50),
      new("Col", 0)
    };
```

**Each `PLayer` that you try to create in here, will also try to create its own list of `PLayers` which repeats infinitely until your computer would crash.**

If you want to be able to create a `PLayer` with custom stats that you can print out, perhaps try approaching it with a `Dictionary` in the `PLayer` class that holds the stats. That way, you could supply a `Dictionary` to the `PLayer` constructor to populate it on instantiation.

Perhaps a `PLayer` class that looked like the following would be better suited for your needs:

```
public class PLayer
    {
        public string Name;
        public bool Dead;

        public PLayer(string name = "", Dictionary<string, int> stats = null)
        {
            Name = name;

            if (stats != null)
                this.Stats = stats;
        }

        Dictionary<string, int> Stats = new Dictionary<string, int>
        {
            { "Health", 100 },
            { "Accuracy", 89 },
            { "Blade Amount", 2},
            { "Blade Damage", 20 },
            { "Blade Lanth", 40 },
            { "Blade durablity", 50 },
            { "Col", 0}

        };



        //all the NPCs you know. 
        List<string> Npc = new List<string> { "levi: ", "Armin: ", "Mikasa: ", "Hange: ", "Erwin: " };
        //skills for killing titans
        List<string> Skills = new List<string>();

        public void PrintStats()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("your stats are: ");
            foreach (var stat in stats)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(575);
                Console.WriteLine(stat.ToString());
            }
        }

    }
```

Which you could then make use of like:

```
class Program
{
     static PLayer Playerstat; 
    
    static void Main()
    {

       Dictionary<string, int> CustomStats = new Dictionary<string, int>
            {
            { "Health", 1000 },
            { "Accuracy", 5 },
            { "Blade Amount", 15},
            { "Blade Damage", 5 },
            { "Blade Lanth", 20 },
            { "Blade durablity", 100 },
            { "Col", 0}

            };

        // Here we actually provide parameters for the constructor
        Playerstat = new PLayer("Example Player Name", CustomStats);


        Console.WriteLine("please pick a mode");
        PLayGame();
        PickMode();
       


        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static void PLayGame()
    {
        List<string> Options = new List<string> { "Easy mode: ", "med mode: ", "Hard mode", "super hard mode: " };
        

        foreach(string ModePick in Options)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(570);
            Console.WriteLine(ModePick);
        }
    }

    private static void PickMode()
    {
        string pick = Console.ReadLine();
        if (pick == "easy")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("you have picked easy.");
        }
            
    }

    
}
```

Comment: ok, but how can I get rid of the [] around each stat and get rid of the comma after the string? also thank you.

Comment: If you're talking about printing out the stats from the `Dictionary`, you'll probably have to change this line `Console.WriteLine(stat.ToString());` to format the information however you actually want it to appear. `stat` should have a `Key` and a `Value` attached to it, so you can print out a string with those values in it (`Console.WriteLine($"{stat.Key}: {stat.Value}");`). You really should heed the other warnings in this thread. It will be difficult to make large projects without proper understanding of some of the most basic aspects of object oriented programming (Object instantiation)

Comment: Regarding `Console.WriteLine($"{stat.Key}: {stat.Value}");` - See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated

Comment: I did take full notes and I'm now aware of them. thank you for the help. it also seems like people on StackOverflow don't really like me that much. or rather my questions that is. sorry for the trouble and thanks again

Comment: I understand where you're coming from. It does seem that way sometimes. I think it has to do with it being blunt delivery of information. On the other hand, there are some pretty basic concepts that seemed to be missing from your question which make it seem like little effort was put in (even if you have been trying hard, we only see what's in the question), so that may be why people are reluctant to answer and would rather link documentation. https://www.w3schools.com/cs/index.php tends to be a good resource when it comes to fundamentals in C# programming, if you were trying to work on that.

Comment: @TheJolt70000 This post may help you when asking questions in the future as well: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: thank you so much. I think that of everyone who has talked to me on StackOverflow and answered me you are the most helpful because #1 you didn't just send me to a website #2 you walked me through it more or less. and #3 you were kind. and I appreciate that. I think I'm going to start from where I left off and watch the documentation of the C# Microsoft videos. I can get the good understanding I need.

Comment: *it also seems like people on StackOverflow don't really like me that much* - it's not the case; you're essentially just a bunch of pixels on a television screen- no one knows enough about you to make any kind of judgment in a "like" way so the majority of it is down to how you're perceiving a limited, emotionless text expression of advice. One of the problems for newbies is that they tend to ask too much; SO has a very narrow focus - post a specific problem in a concise fashion, get a targeted answer. Neither Q nor A has any time wasting pleasantries, thanks/pleas for help/life is hard etc

Comment: The other problem for newbies is that they ask what has been asked before but give us no indication that they've searched for, read, understood but failed to apply advice on we'll work topics. "there is no argument given for one of more parameters" will have been asked hundreds of times when it should really only need asking once; it's very googlable and there should by now be an answer about it that is a worthwhile tome of information on its cause and resolution. If all you do is ask basic questions without giving us any indication what you don't get despite research, then we won't know how..

Comment: ..best to teach you what's missing from your understanding.